# How to fake non-priviledged user in docker container?

Tags: docker

I have to call two commands, the first one is turning on vpn which needs root, the other one is `rpmbuild` which don't want to work on root due to security vulnerabilities. I want to cheat and fake non-root user to call `rpmbuild`. I don't think i would run into security troubles running it under docker in CI, so i want to neglect that

I cannot do

```
USER user  
...  
USER root
```

because all commands run during runtime and in the single script, so i had to manage both paths for default user directories like `/home/user` and `/root`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a specific command in the script as non-root user, you can use the command `su - user -c "<command>"`. After the command specified in `-c` argument is executed, it will go back to run the next commands as root user to turn on the VPN

```
su - user -c "rpmbuild ..." # Run rmpbuild as non-root user
# Turning on VPN as root below
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what i searched for